# karma-browserify throws error when trying to load modules shimmed with browserify-shim

Tags: karma-runner, browserify, browserify-shim

I know there were similar questions but none of them solved my problem.

When I run `karma test` it throws the following error, every time it tries to load a module, that was shimmed with browserify-shim:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'module.exports = ex')
  at /tmp/8ff1e03f7ba1f9c70ee4192510d267a2.browserify:3855:0 <- lib/underscore/underscore.js:1421:0
```

My karma.conf.js is the following:

```
module.exports = function(karma) {
    karma.set({

        frameworks: [ 'jasmine', 'browserify' ],

        files: [
            'test/spec/**/*Spec.js'
        ],

        reporters: [ 'dots' ],

        preprocessors: {
            'test/spec/**/*Spec.js': [ 'browserify' ]
        },

        browsers: [ 'PhantomJS' ],

        logLevel: 'LOG_DEBUG',

        singleRun: true,
        autoWatch: false,

        // browserify configuration
        browserify: {
            debug: true,
            transform: [ 'reactify', 'browserify-shim' ]
        }
    });
};
```

And here is the relevant part of my package.json file:

```
...
  "browser": {
    "underscore": "./lib/underscore/underscore.js",
    "jquery": "./lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "typeahead": "./lib/bootstrap3-typeahead/bootstrap3-typeahead.js",
    "bootstrap": "./lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
    "q": "./lib/q/q.js"
  },
  "browserify-shim": {
    "underscore": "_",
    "jquery": "jQuery",
    "typeahead": {
      "depends": [
        "jquery"
      ]
    }
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "browserify-shim"
    ]
  },
....
```

Any idea what can caus the problem?

Comment: Did you find out the answer?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I decided to use node modules instead of bower components, so I did not need to shim my libraries.  (but I'm still interested in the solution, because I would like to user bower for client side libraries)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and have [resolved it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35561932/error-using-karma-browserify-with-browserify-shim) by removing the browserify-shim transform from karma configuration file, since it is already declared as a transform on package.json file.

Hope that helps.