# Error using karma-browserify with browserify-shim

Tags: gulp, karma-runner, browserify, browserify-shim

I'm trying to use karma-browserify together with browserify-shim with no success. Here is a repo to reproduce the error: https://github.com/pelizza/karma-browserify-shim

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'module.exports = ex')
at /var/folders/_0/ql88mbyd6v34qsmysr5kf4780000gn/T/e0c5e5ebe3f49930de3d988c7196737f.browserify:40308 <- bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:9837:0
```

Everything works fine when bundling with browserify, by it seems that karma simply doesn't find shimmed dependencies when preprocessing files with karma-browserify.

I couldn't find much about this problem, except this one at stack overflow, without a solution: [karma-browserify throws error when trying to load modules shimmed with browserify-shim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29050811/karma-browserify-throws-error-when-trying-to-load-modules-shimmed-with-browserif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution: just remove the browserify-shim transform from the karma configuration file if it was already declared as a transform on package.json.

I have updated the [repo](https://github.com/pelizza/karma-browserify-shim) with this fix.

Here is the discussion about this issue: https://github.com/nikku/karma-browserify/issues/170#issuecomment-187372309